# How can I load multiple optimized requirejs modules dynamically in a production env?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I've started to play with require js on a dummy project. I now want to use the r.js script to build my project for production.

The context is this:

- Main file called start.js is:

  ```
  require([/* some stuff */], function (){ /* app logic */ });
  ```

  which has an if that decides what I should require based on some condition.
- The required files are either ModuleA or ModuleB
- Both ModuleA and ModuleB have dependencies.

  ```
  define([/*some deps*/], function(dep1, dep2...) { 
      /* app logic */ 
      return { /* interface */
  }
  ```
- Everything works fine in development mode, before optimization and module concatenation.
- When building with r.js I specify as module targets the following : 
      modules : [ { name : "start" }, { name : "ModuleA" }, { name : "ModuleB" } ]

The problem is that my ModuleA becomes :

```
 define(dep1 ..);
 define(dep2 ..);
 define(ModuleA ..);
```

But nothings loads from ModuleA. The code from ModeulA in development loads and executes, the code after building loads but does not run.

How could I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

http://pastebin.com/p1xUcY0A --> start.js

http://pastebin.com/dXa6PtpX --> ModuleA js-animation.js

http://pastebin.com/xcCvhLrT --> ModuleB css-animation.js no deps.

http://pastebin.com/j51V5kMt --> The r.js config file used when running the optimizer.

http://pastebin.com/UVkWjwe9 --> How the js-animation.js looks after running r.js. This is the file that has problems. I don't get the js-animation module from this file. The require does not return my js-animation object.

Edit:

After removing the .js at the end of the module definitions and in from start js, the optimized   start.js is http://pastebin.com/LfaLkJaT and the js-animations module is http://pastebin.com/qwnpkCC6. In chrome, I get this error in my console http://pastebin.com/Hq7HGcmm

Comment: I can paste the entire code of the dummy project, it has around 300 lines though.

Comment: put your code on pastebin.com and edit your question and attach your pastebin url :)

Comment: not sure if pastebin is a good options. The projects has 4 js files in dev, and should have 3 in production. :|

Comment: Clarification: does your "start" module have logic outside of the `require` that generates an array of dependencies?  And if so, this array will contain the dependency name "ModuleA" or "ModuleB"?  Maybe you could just add the code for `start.js`...

Comment: Thanks for the comment @rharper. My start.js module has two requires inside it. Only one of the two inner require calls is done based on a condition. Did that clarify my situation?

Comment: @VladNicula I think it would be wise to post a condensed version of `start.js`.  Does `/* some stuff */` in `start.js` include Modules A and/or B?  Are your requires inside start synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @rharper, thanks for offering to help. I updated the question with links to pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is problematic with the current require.js implementation. The way around it was to create a global mediator or mediator module and have all dynamically loaded modules call the mediator and announce themselves via an event. This worked for me.

Comment: I have kinda have the same problem but with packages. When I try to load a minified package my main.js does not execute

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem with your setup is that you end your module dependency names in `.js`.  As per the docs:

> RequireJS also assumes by default that all dependencies are scripts, so it does not expect to see a trailing ".js" suffix on module IDs. RequireJS will automatically add it when translating the module ID to a path.

If RequireJS sees a module name ending in `.js` it assumes that the module name is a path relative to the document.  By ending your module dependency names in `.js` it works fine in development mode because RequireJS will go and load the file specified as a dependency. In your case it will load the file `js/js-animation.js`, see an anonymous `define` and load the module properly.

In production, your `start.js` module still requires `"js/js-animation.js"`.  RequireJS will load your optimized module at the path `js/js-animation.js` but now the optimizer has converted your anonymous modules into named modules (in this case `"js/js-animation"`).  The result is the file will be loaded but no `define`'d modules within the file have a name that matches `"js/js-animation.js"` so in a sense your animation module is missing.

**Solution / TL;DR:** Remove the trailing `.js` from all your module dependency names (and your module definitions in the r.js config) and you should be fine.  So your `start.js` should become (changes on line 4):

```
require([], function () {
  var $html = $("html"),
    animationModule = localStorage['cssanimations'] == 'true' ? 
    'js/css-animation' : 'js/js-animation',
    $doc = $html.find("body");

  console.debug("loading ", animationModule);
  require([animationModule], function( animationModule ) {
    animationModule.run({
      target : $("div.flex")
    });
  } );
} );
```

Also note your may want to use `baseUrl` and `paths` in your RequireJS config to clean up module names (e.g. so you can remove the `js/` prefix).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed response. I appreciate it. I removed the .js from the module names, and the build script now declares modules without the .js at the end of their names. The problem still persists. The second production module, js-animation, has two defines as before, first one for the plugin, second one for itself, and start js still can't get the content from it. :|

Comment: @VladNicula It looks like you made an error editing `start.js`.  You removed `.js` from the end of your module name (good) but also removed the `js/` from the front (which you need to leave).  Your require.js `js-animation` module is literally called `'js/js-animation'` as you can see from the optimized output.  I'm surprised if your code worked in development mode either with this error...  Add `js/` back to your module names in start.js and give it a try.

Comment: the start.js module is in the js folder. If I add /js before my module names I get a "Uncaught Error: Script error" and the url has /js/js/module-name in it, which is wrong...